# Can I use a Ready Action to Trigger an Opponent's Concentration Check?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, readied-action

Suppose, I (PLAYER) choose to Ready.

Next turn, an enemy spellcaster (OPPONENT) casts a spell.

Can PLAYER cast a spell during OPPONENT's turn via 'ready' and force OPPONENT to make a concentration check?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes

The [Ready Rules](https://www.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Ready&Category=Special%20Initiative%20Actions) & [Concentration Rules](https://www.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Concentration&Category=Casting%20Spells) provide two ways of doing so:

**Method 1 – Readying an Action:**

> **Readying an Action:** You can ready a standard action, a move action, a swift action, or a free action. To do so, specify the action
> you will take and the conditions under which you will take it. Then,
> anytime before your next action, you may take the readied action in
> response to that condition. The action occurs just before the action
> that triggers it. If the triggered action is part of another
> character’s activities, you interrupt the other character. Assuming he
> is still capable of doing so, he continues his actions once you
> complete your readied action.

PLAYER can use the standard action of his turn to ready any spell, that he can cast either as a standard action, move action, or swift action with the trigger "if OPPONENT casts a spell".

If PLAYER succeeds in casting the spell, then it triggers a concentration check for OPPONENT. The DC of the concentration check depends on the spell, i.e. if it deals damage or just interferes:

> **Spell:** If you are affected by a spell while attempting to cast a spell of your own, you must make a concentration check or lose the
> spell you are casting. If the spell affecting you deals damage, the DC
> is 10 + the damage taken + the level of the spell you’re casting.
>
> If the spell interferes with you or distracts you in some other way, the
> DC is the spell’s saving throw DC + the level of the spell you’re
> casting. For a spell with no saving throw, it’s the DC that the
> spell’s saving throw would have if a save were allowed (10 + spell
> level + caster’s ability score).

A few spells – e.g. [Distracting Cacophony](https://www.aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Distracting%20Cacophony) – have their own explicit rules on concentration checks, that might modify these general rules on concentration checks.

**Method 2 – Distracting Spellcasters:**

> **Distracting Spellcasters:** You can ready an attack against a spellcaster with the trigger “if she starts casting a spell.” If you
> damage the spellcaster, she may lose the spell she was trying to cast
> (as determined by her concentration check result).

PLAYER can ready a spell attack, e.g. a [Chill Touch](https://www.aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Chill%20Touch) attack or a [Steam Reay Fusillade](https://www.aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Steam%20Ray%20Fusillade) ranged touch attack, with the trigger "if OPPONENT casts a spell".

This only triggers a concentration check when PLAYER successfully damages OPPONENT (see above).